# Datetime format in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I work in MVC c#. I want to modify the datetime display (Project contain some date).

In my class:

```
public ActionResult Edit(long id){
        ...
        return View(project);
    }

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(Project _project){
        ...
        Save(_project);
        return View();
    }
```

In the EditorTemplate:

```
<%:Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}", Model.HasValue ? Model : DateTime.Today), new { @class = "dp" })%>
```

This version works well, bur when I try to modify the format to: `{0:dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm}`, dates in _project are wrong (default value I think).

Comment: I Think, you need to provide more information about the problem and point out where is the error!

Comment: When I use the format "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm}" in the Shared/EditorTemplate/DateTime.ascx I can edit my project. When I  chance the value and save in the view, the controler receive a correct date : _project.date
When I use "{0:dd/MM/yyyy - HH:mm}" my view display the date with the right format, I can change this value, but when I save the controller receive a wrong date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your `Project` model look like? Because in your ternary, you're passing your model if it `HasValue`. I think that would be your problem.

Comment: my model is : 
public partial class Project
    {
        public Project()
        {
            this.Events = new HashSet<Event>();
        }
    
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        ...
        public System.DateTime startDate { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime endDate { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public string quoteNumber { get; set; }
        
    
        public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Event> Events { get; set; }
    }
}